# How do I change which file Render loads?

Tags: reactjs, flask, deployment, render

I'm trying to deploy a web service on Render, but when it deploys it only displays my app.py file from my backend, rather than my frontend created in react. My build command is "   pip install -r requirements.txt && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client" and my start command is "gunicorn app:app". The path to my index.html is "client/public/index.html".

I've also tried several other start commands like npm start and npm run build.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.